# AFNetworking - Check reachability for a domain

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking 2.2.1 and trying to use the AFNetworkReachabilityManager to check if a certain domain is reachable, but it always return NO. Maybe I am not using this correctly and would appreciate any pointers.

```
AFNetworkReachabilityManager *manager = [AFNetworkReachabilityManager managerForDomain:@"www.google.com"];
// always returns NO:
NSLog([manager isReachable] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

I also tried with the startMonitoring method (after the manager variable declaration), but with no luck:

```
[manager startMonitoring];
```

**EDIT:** As David pointed out, needed to add a status change block to get notified:

```
AFNetworkReachabilityManager *manager = [AFNetworkReachabilityManager managerForDomain:@"www.google.com"];
[manager setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status){
    switch (status) {
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN:
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi:
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable:
            NSLog(@"Never called");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Never called");
        break;
    }
}];
[manager startMonitoring];
// always returns NO:
NSLog([manager isReachable] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AFReachabilityManager` does it's magic asynchronously, so the results of `isReachable` aren't valid until it's completed.  The easiest way to be notified when the result of `isReachable` is valid is to use `setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:` to set a status changed block, and do whatever is appropriate when the status is no longer `AFNetworkReachabilityStatusUnknown`

Comment: I also tried the above code with a setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:, but the block is never called.

Comment: You will still need to call startMonitoring.

Comment: I updated the original post with a setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock + startMonitoring call, but the block is never called.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I was calling the stopMonitoring method right after the [manager isReachable] call...