# Why is this reachable at all?

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I have this code to start monitoring and when I test with this made-up domain, I'm still getting a status of reachableViaWWAN. Why?

Using AFNetworking version 2.5.0 from cocoapods. I also tried downloading the latest from github and got the same thing.

```
+ (void)startMonitoring {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        reachabilityManager = [AFNetworkReachabilityManager managerForDomain:@"thisIsNonsense.testSDK.irg"];
    });

    [reachabilityManager setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status){
    switch (status) {
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN:
            NSLog(@"reachable viaWWAN");
            break;
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi:
            NSLog(@"reachable viaWiFi");
            break;
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable:
            NSLog(@"NOT reachable");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"unknown status");
            break;
        }
    }];

    [reachabilityManager startMonitoring];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding how `AFNetworkReachabilityManager` is checking, it looks like it's just using `SCNetworkReachability` which looks like it claims

> A remote host is considered reachable when a data packet, sent by an application into the network stack, can leave the local device. Reachability does not guarantee that the data packet will actually be received by the host.

[docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/SCNetworkReachabilityRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/SCNetworkReachabilityFlags)

Comment: In this case, I would expect the DNS lookup to fail and no packets sent.

Comment: That's a good question - I've never used the `AFNetworkReachabilityManager` myself so I'm not sure of all of its features. It looks like https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFNetworkReachabilityManager.m#L205-L227 is the heart of it that isn't doing much for `AFNetworkReachabilityForName`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23525855/afnetworking-check-reachability-for-a-domain looks like approximately the same type of issue  also

Comment: There was a recent update that was supposed to fix the issue you reference, but I think it is now the opposite of what it was. https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1496